# required css react app background-image

Tags: css, reactjs, background-image

This is probably a simple answer but I'm struggling to find an answer. I have an image as a background for a div. I'm requiring my css file. My css is pretty standard:

```
  background-image: url('assets/placeholders/img-hero.jpg') center center/cover no-repeat;
```

Webpack won't compile it though...says it found an unexpected character.

What am I doing wrong here exactly? Does React have a way of handling this sort of thing that I'm unaware of?

Comment: Any chance you can print the full  error message, the unexpected character message mostly points to where the unexpected character was found, so it could make a change :)

Answer (score 1):

I literally needed a slash in front of assets and to turn it into a string. Sometimes I feel like an idiot. I don't know what the rest of the time is like. Thanks to everyone for their advice!

```
  background-image: url('/assets/placeholders/img-hero.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your value for the `background-position` is invalid indeed. You should only specify the `url()` there and move the rest of the stuff to a separate properties. Something like:

```
 background-image: url(assets/placeholders/img-hero.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
```

Comment: Yeah I guess that was a bad example. That was originally a background: instead of a background-image: 

I still can't get webpack to compile after changing my css to mirror your suggestion. It still throws the same error.

Comment: Try removing the quotes, will update my answer to reflect that